# Removing version control from Sourceforge download

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, sourceforge

I have downloaded a repository from Sourceforge, and it has automatically added version control to the directory (I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows 8). However, I don't want this directory to be part of the version control of the Sourceforge project. How can I download the repository such that it is entirely independent? Alternatively, how can I make a copy of the downloaded directory such that the copied directory is not under version control? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To 'detach' a subversion working copy, simply delete the .svn directory you'll find in the root directory (or, in early versions of svn, in every directory)

To get just a copy of the files in the first place, do an export rather than a checkout.

Comment: Thanks. The export worked well, however I cannot find any .svn directories - instead, I can see a .nuget directory. Is that similar?

Comment: no. .nuget is a completely different thing - a Microsoft equivalent of a package manager.

Comment: @Karnivaurus: the svn-folder is a hidden one. Can you see hidden folders/files in your explorer? For the rest gbjbaanb answer possible solution (+1 for that). For a other way to do please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do detach from SVN you can also use `svn-export`. It will give you a copy of the directory without svn-files/-connection. To create an export with TortoiseSVN just open the context menu:

[image]

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Oh yes you are right. I read over - sorry. So accepting answer should go to you.